# how to show right to left one by one cardview that usage Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, material-design, cardview

i have   card view that usage  horizental RecyclerView.
and i want by scrolling move cards right to left one by one not same list maybe something about tab behaviour.
by user scrolling just scrol to another card.

this is MainActivity class

```js
package ... .myapplication2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
  private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
  private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
  private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
  private Context context;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDataset=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <51 ; i++) {
      mDataset.add("New Title "+i);
    }

    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter=new MainAdapter(mDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(one);


  }

}
```

```js
 this is MainAdapter class 


package... .myapplication2;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

  public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> mDataset) {
    this.mDataset = mDataset;
  }

  @Override
  public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
      .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTitle.setText(mDataset.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 this is activity_main.xml in layout res

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="... .MainActivity">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is row.xml in layout res

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                                    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: please ans to qstn.thanks for your regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two solutions:

**First one to add a SnapHelper:**

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**Second one is to use a Custom ViewPager**...

Comment: Add it in your MainActivity onCreate() method on the bottom, and tell me if it worked